# IConfigureOptions<T> is not creating scoped options

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, coreclr

Typically `Options` are singleton. However i am building options from the database, and one of the Options property is password which keep changing every month. So i wanted to create `Scoped` instance of Options. I am using `IConfigureOptions<T>` like below to build Options from the database

```
public class MyOptions
{
   public string UserID {get;set;}
   public string Password {get;set;
}

public class ConfigureMyOptions : IConfigureOptions<MyOptions>
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    public ConfigureMyOptions(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public void Configure(MyOptions options)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            using (var dbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<MyDBContext>())
            {
                options.Configuration = dbContext.MyOptions
                                        .SingleOrDefault()
                                        .Select(x => new MyOptions()
                                        {
                                            UserID = x.UserID,
                                            Password = x.Password
                                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in controller

```
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly MyOptions _options;
        public HomeController(IOptions<MyOptions> option)
        {
            _options = option.Value;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("home/getvalue")]
        public string GetValue()
        {
            // do something with _options here
            return "Success";
        }
    }
```

I want to create an instance of `MyOptions` for every new request so register it as `Scoped` in startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IConfigureOptions<MyOptions>, ConfigureMyOptions>();
```

However, when i put debugger inside ConfigureMyOptions's Configure method it only gets hit once for the first request. For next request onward the container returns the same instance (like singleton).

How do i set the scope here so MyOptions will get created for each request?

Comment: Is it possible to use this code to modify IConfigureOptions from controller? Because I can't update the values. Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `IOptionsSnapshot` instead of `IOptions` in your controller and it will recreate options per request.

---

Why doesn't work with `IOptions`:

[.AddOptions](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L30-L31) extension method of Configuration API registers the `OptionsManager` instance as a singlethon for `IOptions<>`

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IOptions<>), typeof(OptionsManager<>)));
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped(typeof(IOptionsSnapshot<>), typeof(OptionsManager<>)));
```

and `OptionsManager` class [uses caching internally](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsManager.cs#L39):

```
 public virtual TOptions Get(string name)
 {
     name = name ?? Options.DefaultName;

     // Store the options in our instance cache
     return _cache.GetOrAdd(name, () => _factory.Create(name));
 }
```

*The following issue on github helped to find above: [OptionsSnapshot should always be recreated per request](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/pull/164/files)*

Comment: Why this happens: [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)

Comment: that worked!! I did not know there was `IOptionsSnapshot`  option too